# How to debug binaries from a MIPS firmware

Tags: gdb, mips, firmware

I'm trying to exploit the binaries from Damn vulnerable Router Firmware but I have issues with debuggging with gdb.
to run the program i use this command :
`sudo chroot . ./qemu-mipsel-static ./pwnable/Intro/stack_bof_01`  
and it works but when i try to run gdb with :

```
sudo chroot . ./qemu-mipsel-static gdb ./pwnable/Intro/stack_bof_01
```

I have that :

> (gdb) r
>
> Starting program: /pwnable/Intro/stack_bof_01
>
> qemu: Unsupported syscall: 4026
>
> Cannot exec /bin/bash: No such file or directory.
>
> qemu: Unsupported syscall: 4026
> Could not open /proc/12532/status

I tried to copy the binary in a qemu VM but I don't have the whole system so it don't work.

So , please , what's is the best way to debug a program from a firmware on a different architecture than x86 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In qemu user mode, run the program using the command with the option `-g`:

```
sudo chroot . ./qemu-mipsel-static -g 1234 ./pwnable/Intro/stack_bof_01
```

then start the `gdb-multiarch` (or `gdb` that corresponds to that architecture), and attach to it like this:

```
target remote 127.0.0.1:1234
```

then you can debug it happily.